# "idea net setter" 2g data card not detecting in linux mint 12 but working in windows well

Tags: windows, linux, linux-mint, usb-data-card, usb-modem

My Idea Net Setter data card working in Windows 7 , but not working in Linux mint

Model : EG162G

The data card is USB type , driver and applications are available inside the data card memory for windows 32 bit and 64 bit .

Now i want to use this card in linux mint 12 , But linux OS detect as a memory card only .

Please help me to setup this data card for linux mint 12 OS .

Thanks.

Comment: unmount the memory card device. And you really shouldn't be publishing the IMEI & IMSI numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last it works after many tries .

Linux mint 12 detected the device finally as a data card after doing the following steps.

1. Connected the data card to Laptop usb port and Laptop is connected to broadband already.
2. I clicked update manager icon from task bar and it scanned all hardware & software.
3. Repositories are checked and software packages upgraded automatically.
4. Now the data card has been detected and works well ,i am so surprised because i didn't download or install any software regarding my data card . The Update manager done job automatically when i connected via broadband in my home .
5. Now i am able to setup my mobile broadband option in network settings .

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a utility known as `wvdial`

http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/wvdial